Docker compose down not removing container
For some reason, I keep getting this error where the container name is already being use, I don't always get it on deployment, but it happens frequently enough that it can cause a problem
err: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/***-strapi-1" is already in use by container "f728e54d6ecf05e9be481c94e0f3aa6725ea711ad16ee8feb72cd910818d3ef2". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Even though,in my deployment file in github actions, I clearly down my container stack before deploying it again, what do you think is the error in this case?
  - name: Run the docker-compose.prod.yml stack
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      script: |
        echo ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
        export DATABASE_HOST=${{ secrets.DATABASE_HOST }}
        export DATABASE_PORT=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PORT }}
        export DATABASE_NAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_NAME }}
        export DATABASE_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME }}
        export DATABASE_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
        export APP_KEYS=${{ secrets.APP_KEYS }}
        export API_TOKEN_SALT=${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_SALT }}
        export ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=${{ secrets.ADMIN_JWT_SECRET }}
        export JWT_SECRET=${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
        export R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        export R2_ACCESS_SECRET=${{ secrets.R2_ACCESS_SECRET }}
        export R2_ENDPOINT=${{ secrets.R2_ENDPOINT }}
        export R2_BUCKET=${{ secrets.R2_BUCKET }}
        export R2_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL=${{ secrets.R2_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL }}
        export APP_URL=${{ secrets.APP_URL }}
        docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down
        docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull
        docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d


what you see in the "down" logs?

How can I check them?

why would docker-compose be running already? is that part of the ci/cd vm? this post might be helpful
